# MPI4PY - Why does my while loop only exit on some ranks?

Tags: python, mpi4py

I have parallelised some codes to make frames for a movie. All the ranks exit the while loop except for the one creating the final frame, despite it reaching the end condition. Also I found that it only makes the final frame if I add a CW.Barrier() after the while loop. If that's not there, then it stalls on the second last frame.

```
rank = CW.Get_rank()
size = CW.Get_size()

rit = 0 #rank iterator. Its used to assign frames to make
while len(frames) > 0:
    if rank == rit:
        frame_val = frames.pop() #gets frame
        orit = 0
        while orit < size:
            if orit != rit:
                CW.send(frames, dest=orit, tag=1) #and then sends undated frame list to other ranks
            orit = orit + 1

    #other ranks recieve new list of frames.
    if rank != rit:
        frames = CW.recv(source=rit, tag=1)


    if rank == rit:
        #Creates frame
        print 'Created frame', frame_val, 'on rank', rank

    #iterates through ranks to distribute frames.
    rit = rit +1
    if rit == size:
        rit = 0

CW.Barrier()
print "completed making movie frames on rank", rank
```

Answer (score 0):

Derp, so I didn't provide enough information in my questions. In the

`if rank == rit:
        #Creates frame
        print 'Created frame', frame_val, 'on rank', rank`

It actually looks more like:

`if rank == rit:
        CW.Barrier()
        #Creates frame
        print 'Created frame', frame_val, 'on rank', rank`

Because on some ranks the while look has already exited, not all ranks reach this CW.Barrier() function on the last frames. This barrier isn't actually necessary at this spot at all, so its fixed!